# Get current user logged in in Custom Authentication MVC 4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple login table without simplemembership because in my project i don't need to have a register, the users need to be created automatically in the database. (Made following [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-make-custom-login-register-and-logout-in-mvc-4-usin/)).
I have a model Login:

```
public class Login
    {
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Username { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

and Enrollments:

```
public class Enrollment
    {
        public virtual int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Login> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

And i have a table Enrollment_Login because of the many-to-many relationship.
I need to create a view where i show a list of enrollments that the user logged in is "registered". 
I have this query:

```
var query= from name in db.Enrollments
           where name.Logins.Any(c=>c.LoginId==??)
           select name;
```

If this query is right, how can i get the current user logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the `LoginId` (which I think is a foreign key of your `Login` entity in `Enrollement` entity)

When user is authenticated the the name of that user is stored in `this.User.Identity.Name` if you're in your action method.

The name in your case is the `UserName` property in `Login` entity.

So you must write the following code :

```
var currentLogin = db.Logins.Single(u => u.UserName = this.User.Identity.Name);
var query= from name in db.Enrollments
       where name.Logins.Any(c=>c.LoginId==currentLogin.Id)
       select name;
```

Or in one query:

```
var query= from enrollement in db.Enrollments
       join login in db.Logins on enrollement.LoginId equals login.UserId 
       where login.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name
       select enrollement;
```